# How to show modal view from a xib file in MacOS correctly?

Tags: swift, macos, modal-dialog, xib

OS: MacOS
language: Swift 4+

**What I want**

I want to show a simple custom modal view from my main window. This custom modal view I created in a separate .xib file with belonging NSWindowController class.

In Xcode I added a new file --> CocoaClass --> Subclass of NSWindowController --> Checkmarked "Also create XIB file for user interface"

I than added a button and generated an action handler that simply prints text on the debug console. This to test whether the button press is correctly handled or not.

To show the modal view from my main window I have the following code executed when a button has pressed:

```
let modal = SimpleModal(windowNibName: "SimpleModal")
        self.view.window?.beginSheet(modal.window!, completionHandler: { response in
            print("Finished device selection")
        })
```

This does show the view, but not as a modal view. It simply shows the view next to my main window and the modal view also doesn't react on mouse click events, when I click on the button in the modal view.

I don't know how to get this right, so if you know how to do this, please answer me.

**NOTE:**

When modal view shows up, the main window should be unresponsive until the user dismisses the modal view. It's like moving the focus from main window to the modal view.

The source of my demo project:
[OSXModalView](https://github.com/Nordin-010/OSXModalView)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428436-runmodal

Comment: Do you want to show a modal window or a sheet?

Comment: @Willeke I don't know what's the difference. I once made a MacOS app in Objective-C and made a modal view using sheet. By the way, you can see my project for more details. From what I understand, in MacOS is a modal view, the thing that slides down from the top of the main window. I think that's how it should work on MacOS and not like on Windows popping up a dialog box.

Comment: A modal window is a window like an alert or dialog. A sheet slides down from the top of a window. It is possible to present a view controller as modal window or as sheet. See [presentAsModalWindow(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434462-presentasmodalwindow) and [presentAsSheet(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434489-presentassheet). Or just add the view controller in the storyboard with a modal or sheet segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `Visible At Launch` flag in the attribute inspector of your window object in `SimpleModal.xib`. Otherwise your code works.

Comment: Thnx, this makes it behave as a modal! Just one more thing... (sorry Jobs), when I click on the button in my modal view, it doesn't call the action handler. So my modal view doesn't receive click events (and I guess other UI events too). How to solve that? (If it all works, I accept your answer)

Comment: To dismiss the sheet, simply send call the `dismiss` method of its view controller. The best place to do this is within an action method of a button. Hope that helps.

Comment: I already do that, but once again, my modal view doesn't get click events, so I'm not even able to execute a simple print() because the action handler is not called at all. Thnx.

Comment: mschmidt, I solved it, but don't remember what the final solution was, so I leave your answer as the correct one :)